# Adding feature class to map (within specific group) using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, layers, arcgis-pro

I am trying to add a feature class to my ArcGIS Pro map (a specific group), but I don't seem to be able to find the way.

This is the piece of code I've written:

```py
import arcpy    
arcpy.env.workspace = r'D:\ArcGIS_Pro_Projects\Optimity_Alf'    
fc_output = r'D:\ArcGIS_Pro_Projects\Optimity_Alf\Optimity_Temp.gdb\LOS_Optimity_All_700m'    
fl_output = 'LOS_Optimity_All_700m'
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc_output, fl_output)    
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r'D:\ArcGIS_Pro_Projects\Optimity_Alf\Optimity_Alf.aprx'    
m = aprx.listMaps('MyMap')[0]
m.addLayerToGroup('LOS Results', fl_output)
```

Where 'LOS Results' is the group.

I get the following error: 
    ValueError: LOS Results
    Failed to execute (Testing).

Anyone has any idea?

---

Following @Hornbydd's advice I have run the following code:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'D:\ArcGIS_Pro_Projects\Optimity_Alf'

fc_output = r'D:\ArcGIS_Pro_Projects\Optimity_Alf\Optimity_Temp.gdb\LOS_Optimity_All_700m'
fl_output = 'LOS_Optimity_All_700m'
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc_output, fl_output)

layer = r'D:\ArcGIS_Pro_Projects\Optimity_Alf\Temp\LOS_Optimity_All_700m.lyrx'
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(fl_output, layer, 'ABSOLUTE')

lf = arcpy.mp.LayerFile(layer) # This is pointing to LOS_Optimity_All_700m
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r'D:\ArcGIS_Pro_Projects\Optimity_Alf\Optimity_Alf.aprx')
m = aprx.listMaps('Optimity Map')[0]
refLyr = m.listLayers('LOS Results')[0]
m.addLayerToGroup(refLyr,lf)
```

It doesn't throw any errors but it doesn't add any layer to my map.

Also, is this the only way to do such a simple thing as adding a layer to a map?
I have a feature class in a geodatabase with the data I'd like to plot and I have had to convert that feature class into a feature layer and then that feature layer into a layer file so that it can be displayed. Doesn't it seem over complicated?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question to include the entire error message, including line numbers and any other info.

Comment: Looking at your new update it occurred to me if you want to add the layer to project _that you have open_ then you need to reference the current project. You would do it as: `aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")`. So your code would then be designed to be run in an active document and not as a script say from an IDE. Finally if are trying to insert layers into a group layer using a script from an IDE, then you don't show a line that actually saves your changes...

Comment: That was it. I was not saving the project. Now it works. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is how you are referencing the group layer in `addLayerToGroup()`. To be fair to you it is very easily missed and there are no examples in the Help file to work from (shame on ESRI ;) ).  You need to understand what the help file is saying when you read this method for the [Map Class](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/map-class.htm).

- **Parameter** = target_group_layer
- **Explanation** = A reference to an existing group Layer object.
- **Data Type** = Layer

The **KEY** words here are *Existing Group Layer Object*. You reference your group layer by a *string* (the name of your group layer), that is NOT an existing Layer Object!

You also need to create a LYRX file of your layer (LOS_Optimity_All_700m) and use that.

So create your lyrx file and get a handle on that:

```
lf = arcpy.mp.LayerFile(r"C:\Scratch\test.lyrx") # This is pointing to LOS_Optimity_All_700m
```

Get a handle on the existing group layer object:

```
mygrp = m.listLayers("LOS Results")[0]
```

Then you can add it directly to the group layer:

```
m.addLayerToGroup(mygrp, lf)
```

Comment: I tried as suggested but, although it doesn't throw any error, it doesn't actually add the layer to the map. Also, it's a bit strange that in order to add a layer to a map I need to first convert the feature class that contains the data into a feature layer and then this feature layer into a layer file. Don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

I was recently struggling with the same problem. I created a blank group layer and saved that to a lyrx file on disk. I managed to successfully add a feature class to this group (without creating a separate lyrx file of that fc) by doing something similar to the following (I've tried to adapt to your script):

```
import arcpy
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('CURRENT')
m = aprx.listMaps('*')[0]
outputWorkspace = r'D:\ArcGIS_Pro_Projects\Optimity_Alf'
arcpy.env.workspace = outputWorkspace
fc_output = r'D:\ArcGIS_Pro_Projects\Optimity_Alf\Optimity_Temp.gdb\LOS_Optimity_All_700m'
fl_output = 'LOS_Optimity_All_700m'
blank_group_layer = arcpy.mp.LayerFile(r"\\path\to\layer\file\grp_lyr.lyrx") #created previously in ArcPro and exported as lyrx file
m.addLayer(blank_group_layer, "TOP")
model_output_group = m.listLayers("name of group layer")[0]
fl_output = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc_output, fl_output).getOutput(0)
m.addLayerToGroup(model_output_group, fl_output, "TOP")
```