# Error in ArcGIS Pro when Adding Layer to Group through ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, group-layer

I'm trying to add layers to an empty group layer through arcpy in ArcGIS Pro. I've read that creating empty group layers only works by importing a saved template. I'm able to load my template and it appears in the contents pane. But when I try to add a layer I get the following error.

```py
# Import template
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
in_path = os.path.join(dir_path, r'templates\group_template.lyrx')
groupLayer = arcpy.mp.LayerFile(in_path).listLayers()[0]

# Add group layer to map
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
aprxMap = aprx.activeMap
aprxMap.addLayer(groupLayer, 'TOP')

# Get layer to add
lyr = [l for l in aprxMap.listLayers() if l.name == 'test'][0]

# Add layer to group
aprxMap.addLayerToGroup(groupLayer, lyr)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 191, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\_mp.py", line 1317, in addLayerToGroup
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.addLayerToGroup(*gp_fixargs((target_group_layer, add_layer_or_layerfile, add_position), True)))
ValueError: <MappingLayerObject object at 0x0000000044B73770>
```

If I add the layer with `aprxMap.addLayer(lyr)` everything works fine and `groupLayer.isGroupLayer` returns True (lyr is a feature layer). Also, I'm able to add the layer by drag and drop, but I don't want to do that, since this code should finally be part of a larger function. I also tried converting the layer to a layer file as proposed in this question [Adding feature class to map (within specific group) using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260114/adding-feature-class-to-map-within-specific-group-using-arcpy-with-arcgis-pro), but I still get the error.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to add your layer to your initial group layer object. This is a representation of the layer in the lyrx file, not the one that you've added to your map. After adding the group layer template to the map, you will need to grab that one and then add your layer to it. You could do it like so:

```
# Import template
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
in_path = os.path.join(dir_path, r'templates\group_template.lyrx')
groupLayer = arcpy.mp.LayerFile(in_path).listLayers()[0]

# Add group layer to map
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
aprxMap = aprx.activeMap
aprxMap.addLayer(groupLayer, 'TOP')

# Get layer to add
lyr = [l for l in aprxMap.listLayers() if l.name == 'test'][0]

# Get added group layer - option 1 since you know the name, if you assume the name is unqiue
mapGroupLayer = [lyr for lyr in aprxMap.listLayers(groupLayer.name)][0]

# Get added group layer - option 2 since you add the group to the top, if nothing
# has changed in the map since, it should be the first layer returned
mapGroupLayer = [lyr for lyr in aprxMap.listLayers()][0]


# Add layer to group
aprxMap.addLayerToGroup(mapGroupLayer, lyr)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was missing.